# Exit code non-existent in google

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

A project that uses AirSDK31 is crashing at random momentos while reproducing a video.
The only error I see is this:

[AIR Debug Launcher]: Process finished with exit code -805,306,369

There does not seem to be any other information about it. This code when searched on google, only an error from Minecraft is found. This is not Minecraft.
I'm not sure, but does this have something to do with the adl.exe file?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the error appear when performing a particular action in your application?  can you try to catch the exception, so that you can get more information out? https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html

Comment: After adding many try catch, and testing in many ways, it does not get into the catch. But I got to locate the error. It is related to the VideoPlayer from Feathers UI, probably the Netstream.